# Is there any ranking process for chat rooms and find out which one is popular?

Tags: discussion, chat, stack-exchange, rankings, popularity

How can we check that which chat room is famous among the users and is there any ranking process for them on the basis of number of users or activity per days like that.

Can I find that ranking of my room in India or in world?

Comment: You can view rooms based on various criteria, such as [recently active](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=active) (as mentioned in Vigbyor's answer) or [most populated](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=people). But this is probably not exactly what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot. Like others have pointed out, you can sort the rooms by various criteria, but none of them include a popularity ranking. How would you measure that anyway?

The most frequented and active rooms are usually the four listed on the screenshot below:

[image: chat sorting]

Picking one of the Sort options, sorts the chat rooms by their **current** number of people or activity. Each chat room also lists their total number of messages and people in the info box for the chat room. You cannot sort by the latter, but it's usually the same rooms that are also active atm.

As you can see, Javascript and PHP have seen the most individual people since creation.
The Lounge has the most messages, followed by Javascript and PHP.

Number of messages doesn't necessarily imply popularity though. [The Lounge contains about 22k+ messages containing the F word](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fuck&room=10). A lot of noise. Also, the Lounge is infamous for being only popular among it's regular users and being unfriendly and hostile to anyone else. Oh well. And look at their room description. 'Nuff said?

The People count alone doesn't necessarily imply popularity either, since a lot of users just come to the rooms to ask for help and then never come back again (which might tentatively be an indicator for the popularity of a language, but not of a room).

We could probably count the favorites. That might be an indicator for popularity. But we don't.

**TL;DR:** There is no popularity metric. Chat is not a popularity contest. Just stay in the rooms you like and that feel useful to you.

Comment: This seems very much like you are pushing your own spin onto the numbers. Surely a room with a high people count relative to number of messages would indicate that people aren't sticking around in that room.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's what I said. Neither number of messages, nor people count indicate popularity.

Comment: You said that the lounge was unfriendly and hostile to anyone else (which is reflected by their low people count). That just seems like your personal bias. It doesn't seem like people count would be a good metric for that. You would need to look at number of people that only posted once for example.

Comment: @MartinSmith I am willing to remove the assumption that the people count is related to them being unfriendly since you have to get into the room to witness their hostility. But that they are unfriendly and immature is out of question (that's not bias. It's a fact). And like I said, we have no measure for popularity, nor do I see much use for it. I mean, people should just stay with the rooms they like. It's not a contest who has the most popular room.

Comment: WHAT!? What's with the proper connectors and highlighting being used - I thought free hand circles and lines was the de facto standard for meta examples! :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no ranking system for chat room. However when you visit the htp://chat.stackoverflow.com it displays the chat room based on the current active.